# Remove special character from Summernote when exporting with PHPExcel

Tags: php, excel, special-characters, phpexcel, summernote

I use PHPExcel to export data from database to excel file. But my data contains some special characters, which generated automatically by the editor plugin (Summernote). For example:

```
&lt;p class=&quot;Default&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;color:windowtext&quot;&gt;+ Tra cứu thông tin; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;
```

(The main content is just: **+ Tra cứu thông tin**)

Anyone can help me remove these characters, but keep the original format when exporting to excel file?

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use some basic PHP functions to convert the html entities to their characters, and then strip the html tags:

```
$string = '&lt;p class=&quot;Default&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;color:windowtext&quot;&gt;+ Tra cứu thông tin; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';

$string = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string));
var_dump($string);
```

which will give you the raw text content

```
string(24) "+ Tra cứu thông tin; "
```

---

PHPExcel also provides a Helper function that will convert some html markup so that formatting can be retained by converting it to a Rich Text object

```
$string = '&lt;p class=&quot;Default&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;font-weight: bold;&quot;&gt;&lt;span style=&quot;mso-bidi-font-size:10.0pt;color:windowtext&quot;&gt;+ Tra cứu thông tin; &lt;/span&gt;&lt;/span&gt;&lt;/p&gt;';

$string = html_entity_decode($string);
$wizard = new PHPExcel_Helper_HTML;
$richText = $wizard->toRichTextObject($string);
```

However, if you want to keep all of this original formatting, you'll need to work that out yourself, because PHPExcel's helper doesn't read CSS or read inline styles in `<span>` or `<div>` tags, just basic markup styling tags like `<strong>` or `<i>` or `<font>`.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mark, genius. I made a helper on laravel for this

    function str_fix($string){
        $end = '...';
        if (mb_strwidth($string, 'UTF-8') <= 150) {
            $new_str = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string));
            return $new_str;
        }
$new_str = strip_tags(html_entity_decode($string));
$string = rtrim(mb_strimwidth($new_str, 0, 150, '', 'UTF-8') ).$end;
        return $string;
    }
```